# C# - Trying to solve Kattis Coast Length

Tags: c#, arrays, multidimensional-array, difference

I'm trying to solve this Kattis Coast problem, which I found on website https://open.kattis.com/problems/coast. The goal of the challenge is to calculate the coastline. For that we have been given map of landscape. Which consists of this inupt: 5 6, 011110, 010110, 111000, 000010, 000000. The output or the result should be 20 as a integer.

The idea was to put the input in a jagged array, one for the X-axis(N) and one for the Y-Axis(M). Then looping this arrays and calculate the differenses between land(1) and water(0). This has'nt worked out so I tried hard-coding the accurate coast line by the grid-lines, giving the answer 20.

I don't know if I'm on the right track with arrays and calculating differenses so thats why I'm here asking for help. 
Found this: http://challenge.csc.kth.se/2011/solutions.pdf. At page/slide 3 there is a breif explaination of the coast length problem. It does'nt give me anything but maybe someone gets a grip of it.

Can someone look at my program and point me to the solution?

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.IO;

namespace Task_1  // Coast
{
class Program
{

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        int[][] nboxjaggedarray = new int[5][]
        {
            new int[6]  { 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0 }, // The N-input. Counted from the X-Axis
            new int[6]  { 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0 },
            new int[6]  { 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0 },
            new int[6]  { 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0 },
            new int[6]  { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 }
        };

        int[][] mboxjaggedarray = new int[6][]  // The M-input. Counted from the Y-Axis
        {
            new int[5]  { 0, 0, 1, 0, 0 },
            new int[5]  { 1, 1, 1, 0, 0 },
            new int[5]  { 1, 0, 1, 0, 0 },
            new int[5]  { 1, 1, 0, 0, 0 },
            new int[5]  { 1, 1, 0, 1, 0 },
            new int[5]  { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 }
        };

        int[][] ngridlinesjaggedarray = new int[6][] //Consists of every N-line in the grid. (N = X-Axis)
        {
            new int[6]  { 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0 },
            new int[6]  { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 },
            new int[6]  { 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0 },
            new int[6]  { 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0 },
            new int[6]  { 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0 },
            new int[6]  { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 }
        };

        int[][] mgridlinesjaggedarray = new int[7][] // Consists of every M-line in the grid. (M = Y-Axis)
        {
            new int[5]  { 0, 0, 1, 0, 0 },
            new int[5]  { 1, 1, 0, 0, 0 },
            new int[5]  { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 },
            new int[5]  { 0, 0, 1, 0, 0 },
            new int[5]  { 0, 0, 0, 1, 0 },
            new int[5]  { 1, 1, 0, 1, 0 },
            new int[5]  { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 }
        };



        int ntotal = Sum(ngridlinesjaggedarray);
        int mtotal = Sum(mgridlinesjaggedarray);
        Console.WriteLine(ntotal + mtotal);
        Console.ReadKey();
    }

    public static int Sum(int[][] arr)  // Sums up every item in a JaggedArray
    {
        int total = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < arr.Length; i++)
        {
            if (arr[i] != null)
            {
                for (int j = 0; j < arr[i].Length; j++)
                {
                    total += arr[i][j];
                }
            }
        }
        return total;
    }

}
}
```

Comment: The hard part of the problem is to remove the sea square at location 1,2 and make it a land square so you don't include it in calculating the sea coast.  So 1st step is to analyze each sea square to see if it is part of the sea.  A sea square should be one that connects to other sea squares and eventually connects to the boarder of the game which is a square at row index 0 or 4; or column index 0 or 6.  You can use Dijkstra's algorithm to help find these squares.